# column names changing after a pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe like:

```
ip_src         ip_dst         ip_proto  frame_time_delta payload_size  
192.168.1.101  31.13.94.53    17.0      0.000000         172.0   
31.13.94.53    192.168.1.101  17.0      0.006656         176.0   
192.168.1.101  31.13.94.53    17.0      0.012948         172.0
```

Then, I applied a groupby using some of th columns using:

```
aggregation = {
        'payload_size': {
            'mean_payload_size': 'mean',
            'std_payload_size': 'std',
            'var_payload_size': 'var',
            'max_payload_size': 'max',
            'min_payload_size': 'min',
            'quantity': 'count'
        },
        'frame_time_delta': {
            'mean_frame_time_delta': 'mean',
            'sd_frame_time_delta': 'std',
            'var_frame_time_delta': 'var',
        }
    }

    df = df.groupby(by=['ip_src', 'ip_dst'],as_index=False,).agg(aggregation)
```

but the columns names are awfull, I mean, I get this:

```
ip_src,ip_dst,payload_size,payload_size,payload_size,payload_size,payload_size,payload_size,frame_time_delta,frame_time_delta,frame_time_delta,.....
```

and after that, the names I pointed out in the aggregation dictionary.

How can I fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since dictionary renaming in agg is deprecated we can create multiindex and flatten as one way.

```
aggregation = {
        'payload_size': [
            'mean',
            'std',
            'var',
            'max',
            'min',
            'count'
            ],
        'frame_time_delta': [
            'mean',
            'std',
            'var',
        ]
    }

df_out = df.groupby(by=['ip_src', 'ip_dst']).agg(aggregation)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
         ip_src         ip_dst  mean_payload_size  std_payload_size  var_payload_size  max_payload_size  min_payload_size  count_payload_size  mean_frame_time_delta  std_frame_time_delta  var_frame_time_delta
0  192.168.1.101    31.13.94.53              172.0               0.0               0.0             172.0             172.0                   2               0.006474              0.009156              0.000084
1    31.13.94.53  192.168.1.101              176.0               NaN               NaN             176.0             176.0                   1               0.006656                   NaN                   NaN
```

---

If you want to go a little further and shorted column names you can use `replace`:

```
aggregation = {
        'payload_size': [
            'mean',
            'std',
            'var',
            'max',
            'min',
            'count'
            ],
        'frame_time_delta': [
            'mean',
            'std',
            'var',
        ]
    }

df_out = df.groupby(by=['ip_src', 'ip_dst']).agg(aggregation)
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
df_out = df_out.rename(columns=lambda x: x.replace('payload_size','PLS').replace('frame_time_delta','FTD'))
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
          ip_src         ip_dst  mean_PLS  std_PLS  var_PLS  max_PLS  min_PLS  count_PLS  mean_FTD   std_FTD   var_FTD
0  192.168.1.101    31.13.94.53     172.0      0.0      0.0    172.0    172.0          2  0.006474  0.009156  0.000084
1    31.13.94.53  192.168.1.101     176.0      NaN      NaN    176.0    176.0          1  0.006656       NaN       NaN
```